# C++ OpenCV use vector<Point> as index of a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a matrix `img` (480*640 pixel, float 64 bits) on which I apply a complex mask. After this, I need to multiply my matrix by a value but in order to win time I want to do this multiplication only on the non-zero elements because for now the multiplication is too long because I have to iterate the operation 2000 times on 2000 different matrix but with the same mask. So I found the index (on x/y axes) of the nonzero pixels which I keep in a vector of Point. But I don't succeed to use this vector to do the multplication only on the pixels indexed in this same vector.

Here is an example (with a simple mask) to understand my problem :

```
Mat img_temp(480, 640, CV_64FC1);
Mat img = img_temp.clone();
Mat mask = Mat::ones(img.size(), CV_8UC1);
double value = 3.56;

// Apply mask
img_temp.copyTo(img, mask);

// Finding non zero elements
vector<Point> nonZero;
findNonZero(img, nonZero);

// Previous multiplication (long because on all pixels)
Mat result = img.clone()*value;

// What I wish to do : multiplication only on non-zero pixels (not functional)
Mat result = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_64FC1);
result.at<int>(nonZero) = img.at(nonZero).clone() * value
```

What is tricky is that my pixels are not on a range (for example pixels 3, 4 and 50, 51 on a line).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As I told you in the previous question that you asked that you can use `Mat.convertTo` if you have to multiply a constant value with non-zero elements which would be the fastest. I don't get why you need to find all pixels with non-zero values since you are ultimately multiplying (multiplication with 0?)

Comment: Because I imagine that multiply one image with 90% of 0 is slower than only multiply the 10% different of 0 no? And for you `convertTo` is to convert the value into a matrix for the multiplication I guess.

Comment: _"Because I imagine that multiply... "_ **Don't guess. Profile it!**

Comment: You could basically use convertTo to multiply as well, no need to change the matrix type. I am not sure finding all non-zero coordinates, saving it into vector and then using to multiply would be faster than just using converTo. Why don't you try both?

Comment: Because I am a newbie on openCV and never used `convertTo` but I will investigate this thanks. I didn't understand your first answer sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Mat.convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a3f356665bb0ca452e7d7723ccac9a810). 
Basically, for the parameter `alpha`, which is the scaling factor, use the value of the mask (3.56 in your case). Make sure that the Mat is of type `CV_32` or `CV_64`.

This will be faster than finding all non-zero pixels, saving their coordinates in a Vector and iterating (it was faster for me in Java).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Constructing vector of points will also increase computation time. I think you should consider iterating over all pixels and multiply if the pixel is not equal to zero.

Iterating will be faster if you have the matrix as raw data.

Comment: yes but I create the vector only once and use it at each iteration after. I have at the beginning the memory adress of the first pixel and use it to create a Mat array so I will try iterating from this memory address on two for loops.

Comment: if your image stored in 1d array, you can construct vector of indexes of the non zero pixels. In your case index would be Y*480 + X if the image is grayscale. Then you can manipulate the pixels in one for loop directly accessing from indexes that you already knew.

Comment: Yes I can do only one for loop as you explained, but for a better comprehension it is better to do two for loops I think. The problem is also I have to convert the result as a Mat array to perform other operation after, so I have to investigate all these advices thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
Mat result = img*value;
```

Instead of

```
Mat result = img.clone()*value;
```

The speed will be almost 10 times as fast

I have also tested your suggestion with vector but this is even slower than your first solution.
Below the code I used to test your firs suggestion

```
cv::Mat multMask(cv::Mat &img, std::vector<cv::Point> mask, double fact)
{
    if (img.type() != CV_64FC1) throw "invalid format";
    cv::Mat res = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
    int iLen = (int)mask.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < iLen; i++)
    {
        cv::Point &p = mask[i];
        ((double*)(res.data + res.step.p[0] * p.y))[p.x] = ((double*)(img.data + img.step.p[0] * p.y))[p.x] * fact;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem then because this simple innocent looking clone makes a speed difference of 10 times.

Comment: I didn't know so when I wrote the example I didn't have this in mind sorry.

Comment: I have added the code of your suggestion so you can test it for yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I discovered the step attributes of a Mat array because of you ^^